# Grouping by similar lists in a column within a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, nested-loops

I have a dataframe which has a column of lists.
I want to group the rows which have similar lists, irrespective of the order of the items in the list. Each list can occur multiple times within the column. I want the grouped lists sorted according to number of occurences within the column.

```
data = [['a', ['tiger', 'cat', 'lion']], ['b', ['dolphin', 'goldfish', 'shark']], ['c', ['lion', 'cat', 'tiger']], ['d', ['bee', 'cat', 'tiger']],\
       ['e', ['cat', 'lion', 'tiger']],  ['f', ['cat', 'bee', 'tiger']], ['g', ['shark', 'goldfish', 'dolphin']]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['ID', 'animals']
```

```
df
   ID   animals
0   a   [tiger, cat, lion]
1   b   [dolphin, goldfish, shark]
2   c   [lion, cat, tiger]
3   d   [bee, cat, tiger]
4   e   [cat, lion, tiger]
5   f   [cat, bee, tiger]
6   g   [shark, goldfish, dolphin]
```

I want to group the similar lists in the above dataframe. The order of the animals in the list, can be different.
I am currently using the below code to do this:

```
import collections as cs
animals_grouped = pd.DataFrame()
for q in range(len(df)):
    for r in range(len(df)):
        if (cs.Counter(df.iloc[q]['animals']) == cs.Counter(df.iloc[r]['animals'])):
            animals_grouped = animals_grouped.append(df.iloc[[r]], ignore_index = True)
            
animals_grouped.drop_duplicates('ID').reset_index(drop = True)
```

Result:

```
animals_grouped

    ID  animals
0   a   [tiger, cat, lion]
1   c   [lion, cat, tiger]
2   e   [cat, lion, tiger]
3   b   [dolphin, goldfish, shark]
4   g   [shark, goldfish, dolphin]
5   d   [bee, cat, tiger]
6   f   [cat, bee, tiger
```

Considering I have 100,000+ rows in my original dataframe, what is the alternative to this nested for loop.

Comment: have your considered using `DataFrame.groupby` method? what fucntion do you want to execute on each group?

Comment: How long are the lists and if similar, do the animals always appear in the same order with the same upper/lowercase spelling?

Comment: @Tabaraei pandas groupby will also be terrible for performance as the key is a python list object. If these lists can be converted into a bytestring array (granted, they have to be small enough) it might help. Another thing to consider is how many unique lists there are. If the lists can be "massaged" into a column that is easily hashable, pandas groupby should work well.

Comment: @luthervespers the lists have 3 items. No the animals can appear in any order, order of animals should not matter while grouping. Spellings are the same, but case isn't always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [['a', ['tiger', 'cat', 'lion']], ['b', ['dolphin', 'goldfish', 'shark']], ['c', ['lion', 'cat', 'tiger']], ['d', ['bee', 'cat', 'tiger']],\
       ['e', ['cat', 'lion', 'tiger']],  ['f', ['cat', 'bee', 'tiger']], ['g', ['shark', 'goldfish', 'dolphin']]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['ID', 'animals']
df1 = df.assign(temp=df.animals.apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(x))))
df = df1.assign(temp2 =df1.groupby(df1['temp'].values)['temp'].transform('count')).sort_values(['temp2','temp'], ascending=False).drop(['temp','temp2'], 1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
  ID                     animals
0  a          [tiger, cat, lion]
2  c          [lion, cat, tiger]
4  e          [cat, lion, tiger]
1  b  [dolphin, goldfish, shark]
6  g  [shark, goldfish, dolphin]
3  d           [bee, cat, tiger]
5  f           [cat, bee, tiger]
```

Comment: I think this takes into account the order of items in the list. The order of items in the list should not matter.

Comment: @vikingd. see the updated answer. Change the `ascending=False` to `True` if you wanna sort in the reverse direction.

Comment: I tried your code, with an updated dataframe. 
`data = [['a', ['tiger', 'cat', 'lion']], ['b', ['dolphin', 'goldfish', 'shark']], ['c', ['lion', 'cat', 'tiger']], ['d', ['bee', 'cat', 'tiger']], \
       ['e', ['cat', 'lion', 'tiger']],  ['f', ['cat', 'bee', 'tiger']], ['g', ['shark', 'goldfish', 'dolphin']]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['ID', 'animals']`
This doesn't consider when there are multiple lists occurring same number of times.

Comment: @vikingd can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp sort key by sorting the list, sort the df and then drop it.

```
(
    df.assign(sort_key = df.animals.apply(sorted))
    .sort_values('sort_key')
    .drop('sort_key', axis=1)
)

    ID  animals
0   a   [cat, lion, tiger]
2   c   [cat, lion, tiger]
1   b   [dolphin, goldfish, shark]
```

Comment: I have edited the question to be more precise.